# Is Language a social fiction or a social reality?

Tags: sociolinguistics

Is Language a social fiction? 
I'm required to write an essay about the following : "Is language a social fiction?" and honestly I've had a hard time to determine whether language is a social fiction or a social reality and WHEN CAN LANGUAGE BE A SOCIAL FICTION ?!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you define what you mean by those terms?

Comment: Clearly the answer to that question is Yes. It is both social reality (e.g, here we are in more or less real life, using a version of language socially -- though I have no guarantee that you are perceiving the same social reality as I am) **and**  a whole buncha social fictions (e.g, "correct usage" and the "Universal Grammar" hypothesis). It's a breath mint **and** a candy mint.

Comment: This question might work out better at philosophy.SE

Answer (score 3):

According to [Sapir-Whorf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_relativity) hypothesis, language is a cognitive mechanism defining our cognitional patterns and therefore defining our [social] realities. Their works, as many more Whorfianist works, are easily accessible online.

According to Daniel Everett, language is [by convention] a cultural  phenomenon. [Here is a site with his bibliography and some of Dan's publications](http://daneverettbooks.com).

According to [Ruth Millikan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruth_Millikan), language is a form of biological communication and as such is a property of non-human living [social] species as well - although they don't have to be *quite* social. The truth, as usual, is relative and *out there*.